# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. - Spring Boot - JSP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I am new to Spring Boot, trying to build a web application using JSP with Spring Boot, getting the fallback error I have given the path exactly.

Please refer the below link. where I created the WEb_INF and path
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-qkoy49zIZe-Y6-zPeAn9g2aRGaDHt01/view?usp=sharing

#### File *CustomerContoller.java*

```java
package com.javabrains.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    public String hello(ModelMap Model) {
        return "list";
    }
}
```

#### File *application.properties*

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

#### File *pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- Look up parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>javabrains</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Stack trace

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-08 11:32:00.571  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] com.javabrains.WebDemoApplication        : Starting WebDemoApplication on NagaTeja with PID 6484 (C:\Users\nagat\workspace1\WebDemo\target\classes started by nagat in C:\Users\nagat\workspace1\WebDemo)
2019-09-08 11:32:00.575  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] com.javabrains.WebDemoApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-08 11:32:00.626  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-09-08 11:32:00.626  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-09-08 11:32:01.644  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5bc3870] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-08 11:32:01.699  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-09-08 11:32:02.286  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-08 11:32:02.321  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-08 11:32:02.322  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-08 11:32:02.605  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-09-08 11:32:02.612  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-08 11:32:02.613  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1987 ms
2019-09-08 11:32:02.904  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-08 11:32:03.235  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-09-08 11:32:03.310  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-08 11:32:03.313  INFO 6484 --- [  restartedMain] com.javabrains.WebDemoApplication        : Started WebDemoApplication in 3.191 seconds (JVM running for 3.903)
2019-09-08 11:32:16.663  INFO 6484 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-08 11:32:16.663  INFO 6484 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-09-08 11:32:16.671  INFO 6484 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
```

I expect the *list.jsp* file should run successfully without any problems. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: can you update complete stack trace

Comment: Can you check my answer ?

Comment: @Santos it is the full stack trace

Comment: I guess the xml file name has a typo...

Comment: *"`porn.xml`"*??? Not *"`pom.xml`"*?

Comment: Was it retyped from somewhere? Is the file name actually "`CustomerContoller.java`"? Not "`CustomerController.java`" (missing `r`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is happening because you haven't added any map on your method inside your controller. So add a map on a method like

```
@GetMapping(value="")
public String hello(ModelMap Model) {
    return "list";
}
```

After running the project, open your browser and hit `localhost:8080/customer`.

Comment: It's working fine thanks for the help. Can you help me understand as per my knowledge @GetMapping is used in RestControllers but this normal controller? help me to understand this.

Comment: @NagaTeja As spring update it's version it optimizing its code such as we used 
`RequestMapping(value="" Method=GET)` earlier but now we can use `GetMapping(value="")` or`PostMapping(value="")` instead.